# Slider won't work in result in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, css, static, slider, jsfiddle

I'm brand new to coding and so started out in codecademy. My JQuery code worked fine there for my carousel image slider, but when I tried it out in jsfiddle, it's static, just stays on one image.

Here is the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $slider = $('.slider'); 
  var $slide = 'img';
  var $transition_time = 25 00;
  var $time_between_slides = 4000; 

  function slides(){
    return $slider.find($slide);
  }

  slides().fadeOut();

  // set active classes
  slides().first().addClass('active');
  slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

  // auto scroll 
  $interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
      ,$transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
  );
});
```

The images to be placed in the slider are stored as follows:

```
<div id="jumbotron"> 
 <div class="slider">
    <img class="img" src="http://photos.travellerspoint.com/203325/Peru_239.jpg" width="100%">
    <img class="img" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3367/5734521147_ab8fa45d8a.jpg" width="100%">
    <img class="img"src="http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I0000aT96V0jJZX4/s/650/650/Alpaca-Wool-Factory-El-Alto-Bolivia-17.jpg" width="100%"> 
    <img class="img"src="https://kitaliana.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/rug_cusco1.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
</div>
```

This is the first I've ever coded, so I really had no idea where to look when the code worked in one case and not in another, even though the code is identical...

Comment: Did you load  the libraries jQuery,bootstrap(if any).

Comment: BTW: Javascript isn't PHP. Every variable doesn't need to start with a `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
var $transition_time = 2500;
```

Instead of:

```
var $transition_time = 25 00;
```